# Cauchy's Theorem on Path Integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Cauchy's Integral theorem: Let $U$ be a convex open set and suppose $f$ is a function which is analytic on $U$, except possibly at one point, where it is at least continuous. Then $$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz=0$$
for every closed path in $U$.

Let $\gamma$ trace the unit circle centered at $0+0i$ in the anticlockwise direction on the set $\mathbb{C}$.

Then, $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z^2} dz = 0$, which makes sense.

But then why does $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z} dz = 2\pi i$?

Both $\frac{1}{z}$ and $\frac{1}{z^2}$ are not defined at $z=0$, but then how does Cauchy's theorem only apply to the latter?

Comment: Why does the version of Cauchy's Theorem that you stated work for the function $\frac{1}{z^2}$? Any open convex set containing the trace of the curve in question must contain the origin, but this function is not continuous at the origin, even if it is analytic everywhere else.

Comment: $\gamma (t) = \cos(t) + i\sin(t)$, so $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\gamma (t)) \gamma '(t) dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{it}}{e^{2it}} dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi} ie^{-it} dt = 0$

Comment: I am familiar with this calculation, but what I was trying to say is that this has nothing to do with the theorem you mentioned, since it's conditions are not even satisfied. The answer below shows that this result is actually related to the existence of a primitive of the function $\frac{1}{z^2}$ in $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler look at the problem from "another" [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) perspective, stating:

$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$

In this case $a=0$ and $f(z)=1$

- for $n=0$ $$1=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz$$
- for $n=1$ $$1'=0=\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^2}dz$$

Answer (score 2):

In fact Cauchy theorem applies when the open set $U$ is [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) which is the case of convex sets.

More generally if, on $U$, your function $f$ admits an antiderivative (that is $F$ such that $F'=f$), one has 
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0
$$
for arbitrary $U$.

In your case $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$ admits $F(z)=-\frac{1}{z}$ as antiderivative on $\mathbb{C}^*$ whereas $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ does not.

In fact, one can prove the following (can be elaborated on request)

> **Lemma** Let $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ open and $f$ analytic on $U$. Then $f$ admits an antiderivative on $U$ iff $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0$ for all closed path $\gamma$ in $U$.

Comment: Wouldn't the antiderivative of 1/z just be $\ln z$?

Comment: @SatD Not on $\mathbb{C}^*$ but on the slit plane ($\mathbb{C}\setminus ]-\infty,0]$ for the principal determination).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to elaborate Duchamp’s answer:

Suppose $\ln(z)$ is a well defined function.

Obviously, $$e^{0}=e^{2\pi i}$$ Taking logarithm on both sides, $$\ln(e^{0})=\ln(e^{2\pi i})$$$$0=2 \pi i$$ which is paradoxical.

Therefore we concluded that $\ln(z)$ is not well defined. In fact, it is illegal to take log on both sides when dealing with complex numbers.

Although $e^{0}$ and $e^{2\pi i}$ refers to the same point on the complex plane, their logarithm is different. This property violates the definition of a function.

Actually, because the problematic $\ln(z)$ happens to be the *supposed* antiderivative of $\dfrac{1}{z}$, the contour integration of $\dfrac{1}{z}$ on the unit circle is not zero as expected^^, but $2 \pi i$ instead.

^^If you have some physics knowledge, walking around a point and then return to the original position do not change most physical states, for example: electric field strength, energy, work done......

Comment: Well, I would not call it illegal to take logarithms of both sides of an equation when dealing with complex variables. You are just saying that a function gives the same image if applied to equal elements. What is illegal is saying that $\log(\exp z) = z$ holds for every complex number $z$.